# how can I add an image to the mail template?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I can't add an image from any wwwroot folder to the template I'm going to send by mail

```
var mailTemplate = repoEmail.GetItem(tip).Result;
        if (mailTemplate == null)
            return;

        var mesaj = Regex.Replace(mailTemplate.Body, Reg,
            x => x.ToString()
                .Replace("[Name]", firstName)
                .Replace("[LastName]", lastName)
                .Replace("[Date]", date)
                .Replace("[Product]", product)
                .Replace("[URL]", url)
                .Replace("[PICTURE1]", "/assets/icon-positive-vote-1.png"));
```

Template

```
 <img alt="Logo" src="[PICTURE1]" />
```

The folder orientation of the image is absolutely correct. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The image should be an absolute URL I think, so the mail reader can reach to your website and download the image.

Comment: @Jonathan https://localhost:port/assets/icon-positive-vote-1.png that doesn't work either

Comment: localhost:port/assets/icon-positive-vote-1.png Try this path on the browser while running your project. Did you able to see the Image?

Comment: @FahadEjazButt Yes, i can see

Comment: Show mail source then for further info. Also mail should be open on same browser while testing on localhost.

Comment: The mail is HTML format and attachments are MIME.  A MIME attachment starts with two dashes on a new line.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)?force_isolation=true